# Profile "SKAdNetwork Developer Testing" has an invalid signature

Tags: ios, swift, storekit, swiftystorekit, skadnetwork

I am trying to download to my iPhone SKADNetwork profile and every time it pops us this error:

```
Profile Error: Profile "SKAdNetwork Developer Testing" has an invalid signature.
```

We need this profile for testing. Anybody has encountered it before?
In case it is relevant: my company renewed the yearly membership a few days ago and I have Developer Mode activated on my iPhone.
[image]

I tried on different phones and everywhere same error

Comment: Did you add your test iPhone Identifier to the provisioning?

Comment: yes it is there